# PDO bindParam() with multiple named parameters

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, prepared-statement

**Can't PDO bind a value to multiple occurrences of a param in a query with a single bindParam()?**

I'm surprised, I thought it was possible, but I didn't find any info on php's docs on this, neither on the web. Any clarification / alternative is welcome!

*Note : I'm using php 5.3.6 / 5.3.8 (dev/prod)*

---

#### Example :

Consider this prepared statement :

```
INSERT INTO table VALUES (:param1, 0), (:param1, 1);
```

Now, if I bind values to my query:

```
bindParam(":param1",$my_param1);
```

I have a PDO error :

> SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number

Comment: Does `bindValue` work fine?

Comment: @h2ooooooo No, same behavior...

Comment: You say that you get a PDO syntax error. What's the exact error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [PDO::prepare](http://www.php.net/manual/de/pdo.prepare.php)

```
You cannot use a named parameter marker of the same name twice in a prepared statement
```

Comment: Correct. It's not supported, it's documented and it's probably not going to change. But neither PDO itself nor the drivers seem to enforce the restriction: you'll find that it *works* with some driver/settings and fails with other.

Comment: Ok, I wasn't looking at the right place... Too bad it's like that. Any idea of alternative binding with PDO, which could allow multiple binds in one shot, without named parameters?